# Problems with filename encoding on Linux when created through Java

Tags: java, linux, encoding

I'm having a problem, and I've been stuck with it for quite some time now. The problem is, I can't get file names to support special characters (only file names, file content is ok). Instead of them, file name is created with question marks.

Now, from what I know (and I could very well be missing something very obvious), Linux itself is set up properly. Locale command will print out the following, which I believe is fine:

```
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=
```

This is my Java code I've written for testing purposes. Not everything is there to keep things clear (like finally block), but everything that matters is. I've also tried variations on the theme using BufferedOutputStream but the result is the same.

```
    String exampleString="I'm in the file: \u0160 \u0161 \u010C \u010D";
    String filename="I'm the filename \u0160\u0161\u010C\u010D.txt";

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(transferDir.getPath()
                + File.separator + "_"
                + filename);

        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int counter;
        while ((counter = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, counter);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tried starting the program with **file.encoding** and **sun.jnu.encoding** properties, but that changed nothing.

I'm starting to question if the truth is really out there, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the files are created with the *names* containing question marks? Or is only you terminal unable to *display* the characters? Please include the name as you want it to be.

Comment: (`fos.close()` called?)

Comment: Try dumping `File.listFiles(...)` to a file for analysis.

Comment: I'm as sure as I can be. For instance, if I list those files with a browser app, thus not using Putty or WinSCP (which are setup to display UTF-8), question marks are still there.

Example of a file name that does not work as I would have expected is "I'm in the filename: šđžćč".

Listing the files will also display questions marks, for example:

`07:46:05,367  DEBUG Directory lib64
07:46:05,367  DEBUG File alfresco.log.2015-03-13
07:46:05,367  DEBUG File alfresco.log.2015-04-20
07:46:05,367  DEBUG File _test????.txt
07:46:05,367  DEBUG Directory srv
07:46:05,367  DEBUG Directory cgroup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears this is a long standing bug in the older File API. I've solved all my problems - with no additional configs of any kind - **by switching to the newer java.nio package**.

Answer (score 0):

And where do you get to see the question marks in the filenames ?  It might be that your console in which you are trying to do ls -l (or whatever) simply does not have the glyphs to render your exotic characters appropriately.

After creating such a file, try opening it using the name as expected and the name with question marks.  You'll know soon enough whether the name itself really got messed up during file creation.

Comment: I'm using both Putty and WinSCP, and both are setup up with support for UTF-8. This is a good idea, but I made sure to not make this mistake. Thanks for the idea, though.